# What is the "$0 =~ s!.*/!!" meaning in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to know the meaning of

```
    "$0 =~ s!.*/!!"
```

in perl , and how can I learn this grammer ？
Welcome all kinds of answers.

Comment: Consult the perl reference documentation; [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (`$0`), [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) (`=~` and `s///`), and [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (`.*/`) are relevant here. A good book doesn't hurt either :)

Comment: ... Unless it really is inside double quotes, in which case the `perlop` parts are just literal elements of that string.

Comment: @tripleee Oh goodness! I didn't even consider that :>

Comment: Would it perhaps be a less sophisticated way of writing `use File::Basename; $0 = basename($0);`

Comment: @TLP It doesn't involve printing `$0` at this point.  But yes, `$0 = basename($0)` would probably be clearer and more portable. (But honestly, who cares about portability to Wintendo DS?)

Comment: @tripleee Oh right, fixed. This is of course assuming there are no double quotes, I was thinking the exact same thing. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This truncates the name of the script (`$0`) to just its basename.  It is useful for diagnostics.  Without the truncation, your warning messages

```
warn "$0: Failed to mumble"
```

would come out as

```
weird/long/path/to/mumble.pl: Failed to mumble at line 3.
```

whereas with the truncation, it shows

```
mumble.pl: Failed to mumble at line 3.
```

So it's just a readability tweak for warning messages, really.  But it's a common idiom.

The hard part for a beginner is probably the realization that `s!foo!bar!` is just another way to say `s/foo/bar/`.  This is a godsend when you need to perform substitutions on strings which contain slashes.  Without this syntactic sugar, you would need to backslash the slashes `s/.*\///` which for a single slash isn't too ghastly, but it quickly leads to [leaning toothpicks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Comment: In retrospect, maybe the example should have included "switching to stuttering mode".

Comment: yes, the hard part is the realization that s!foo!bar for a beginner.